# Cloud9 tries to recreate .settings file

Tags: cloud9-ide

I've installed Cloud9 IDE on my linux machine in order to play around with it a bit (I had to use nodejs 0.8 because cloud9 uses a package that depends on node-waf, which is no longer supported by higher versions of nodejs).

I can start it up without problems, however when I try to access Cloud9 via browser, it constantly gives me the error message: `File already exists.`. Here's a trace from the log:

```
Error: File already exists.
  at module.exports.from (/home/xyz/repos/cloud9/node_modules/vfs-local/localfs.js:678:35)
  at Object.fs.exists [as oncomplete] (fs.js:91:19)
```

Relevant code section:

```
exists(topath, function(exists){
                  if (options.overwrite || !exists) {
                      // Rename the file
                      fs.rename(frompath, topath, function (err) {
                          if (err) return callback(err);

                          // Rename metadata
                          if (options.metadata !== false) {
                              rename(WSMETAPATH + from, {
                                  to: WSMETAPATH + to,
                                  metadata: false
                              }, function(err){
                                  callback(null, meta);
                              });
                          }
                      });
                  }
                  else {
                      var err = new Error("File already exists.");
                      err.code = "EEXIST";
                      callback(err);
                  }
```

When the error occurs, the `topath` variable is set to the workspace settings file (`/home/xyz/repos/cloud9/workspace/.settings`)

Has anyone else had an error like this? How can I resolve it?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

### Reinstalling cloud9

First option, maybe you could try using this workaround installation procedure:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/issues/2904#issuecomment-22518669

Second option, if you are willing to always use an older node-version for running cloud9 as you indicated, I used the following installation procedure and it worked (assuming you already installed [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)). Then you can still use the *cloud9.sh*-file for starting:

```
git clone git://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9.git
cd cloud9
nvm install 0.8.8
sed -i -e 's/~//g' package.json
npm config set ca=""
npm install
sed -i s/connect.session.file/connect.session.memory/ configs/default.js
```

Not sure if 0.8.8 is the best node-version for cloud9 but it works for me :)
Last step seems necessary because of https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/issues/2005#issuecomment-11372587 :)

Then before starting cloud9 you always have to enter:

```
nvm use 0.8.8
```

Or you set 0.8.8 as the default node version if you don't use node much otherwise:

```
nvm alias default 0.8.8
```

### Fix problem without reinstalling

Third option, if you don't want to repeat the installation procedure you could try just reinstalling the *vfs-local*-module in the cloud9 directory:

```
npm install vfs-local@0.3.4
```

Haven't tested this though :)